# How to round float numbers in Haskell just like in C using printf?

Tags: haskell, floating-point, printf, precision, number-formatting

I have a simple code to read a float number and print it with six decimal places.

I have my C code working and I want to make an equal one to Haskell language without installing any extra library.

My solution is absolutely simple in C and Haskell:

**C:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    float n = 123.141568;
    printf("%.6f\n", n); // 123.141571
    return 0;
}
```

**Haskell:**

```
import Text.Printf (printf)
main = do
  let n = 123.141568 :: Float
  printf "%.6f\n" n -- 123.141570
```

The codes are working fine for most numbers, but there are some different results. For example, when `n = 123.141568` the C program outputs `123.141571` and the Haskell one prints `123.141570`. If I change from `Float` to `Double` in Haskell the result is `123.141568`.

My goal is to make my Haskell code equal to C. I realized the rounding methods are different even using printf in both languages but I don't know how it happens.

I tried to make my custom rounding function, but the results were the same to `Float` (in the example above `123.141570`) and `Double` (`123.141568`):

```
customRound x n = fromIntegral (round (x * 10^n)) / 10^n
```

Any idea about how to solve this question?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: 32-bit `float` holds about 7 decimal digits. `123.141568` is not exactly representable as `float`. The closest exactly representable number is 123.141571044921875. If you use `%.15f` a typical C printf will print exactly that (even though the C standard doesn't specify that), while Haskell printf will print `123.141570000000000`. Everything beyond the 5th digit after the decimal point is noise anyway, but if you need it, the easiest way to get it is simply `printf "%.6f\n" $ float2double n`.

Comment: `n = 123.141568` is not exactly representable in `float`, `double` or `long double`.  @eightShirt, post a [mcve] to clearly present your code.

Comment: Thank you @n.m.willseey'allonReddit, your solution using GHC.Float (float2Double) was enough for me.

Comment: @eightShirt, Given "print it with six decimal places." and `float n`, I suggest your goal is misplaced.  Floating point number deserve a "print it with six **significant** decimal places." instead.  Use `printf("%.5e\n", n);` or `printf("%.6g\n", n);`